# Post JSON in android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I want to post String data over HttpClient in android
but i'm tired after receive response status code 503 - service unavailable and 
return response as Html code for our url.

I write in the following Code in JAVA Application and i return the data but when I write the same code in Android Application i receive an exception file I/O not found, I'm Puzzled for this case:

```
public void goButton(View v)
{

   try{
      URL url = new URL("https://xxxxxxxxx");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Test ts= new ApiRequest("null","getUserbyID",new String[] {                                         "66868706" });

        String payLoad = ts.toString();    //toSting is override method that create //JSON Object
        System.out.println("--->>> " + payLoad);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("=================>>> "+ payLoad);


    wr.write(payLoad);
    wr.flush();
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new nputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String line;
   while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println("-->> " + line);
  response += line;
  }
  wr.close();
   rd.close();
    System.out.println("=================>>> "+ response);


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("=================>>> " + e.toString());
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I try to put this code in AsynTask, Thread but i receive the same response status code.
I write in the following Android code as an example data

```
public void goButton(View v)
{
 try{
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(),
     10000); // Timeout Limit
     HttpResponse response;

     String url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

     JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

     try {

     HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
     post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
     json.put("service","null");
     json.put("method", getUserByID.toString());
     json.put("parameters", "1111");
     System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>" + json.toString());

     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
     se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
     "application/json"));
     post.setEntity(se);

             String response = client.execute(post);

     if (response != null) {
     String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

     System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>" + temp);
     }
     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>" + e.getMessage());

     }
     }
     }).start();
}
```

Please Help me to find solution for this problem :(

Thank you in advance

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: Logcat? Well, if a server issues a 503 status I'd primarily be interested in the _server log_ because it will indicate why the 503 error was issued.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an code snippet , hoping it will help you.

1)An function which carries the http get service

```
   private String SendDataFromAndroidDevice() {
    String result = "";

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet("your url + data appended");

        BufferedReader in = null;
        BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient
                .execute(getMethod);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse
                .getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        result = sb.toString(); 


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

2) An Class which extends AsyncTask

```
   private class HTTPdemo extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = SendDataFromAndroidDevice();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result != null && !result.equals("")) {
            try {
                JSONObject resObject = new JSONObject(result);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3) Inside your onCreate method

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView("your layout");



    if ("check here where network/internet is avaliable") {

        new HTTPdemo().execute("");
    }

   }
```

This code snippet ,
Android device will send the data via URL towards Server 
now server needs to fetch that data from the URL

Comment: Thank you for replay, but the api can't fetch data from url , they handle it what type of data request and what data fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

*Hey Mohammed Saleem*

The code snippet provided by me works in the following way,

1)**Android device send the URL+data to server**

2)**Server [*say ASP.NET platform used*] receive the data and gives an acknowledgement**

Now the Code which should be written at client side (Android) is provided to you, the later part of receiving that data at server is

- Server needs to receive the data
- An webservice should be used to do that
- Implement an webservice at server side
- The webservice will be invoked whenever android will push the URL+data
- Once you have the data ,manipulated it as you want